# the pk=request i have some errors in it. i cant seems to link my reserve to another page because of this error

Tags: error-handling, django-views

```
def reserve(request):
if request.method=="POST":
    user=User.objects.get(pk=request.POST['user'])
    **book = Book.objects.get(pk=request.POST['book'])**
    book.isAvailable=True
    book.save()
    reservation=Reserve(dateLoaned=datetime.now(),book=book, user=user)
    reservation.save()
    reservations=Reserve.objects.all()
    return redirect('/library/reservations/')
else:
    user=User.objects.all()
    book=Book.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'reserve.html',{"users":user, "book":book})
```

There is some error in my book = Book.objects.get(pk=request.post[book'])
Im doing a project that needs to be submitted on Monday. PLS HELP!

reserve.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{%  block title %}
Reserve
{% endblock %} 
{% block maincontent %}
    <form action="../reserve/" method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
    <br>
      <div class="table">
          <input value="{{ book.title }}" class="form-control"
               id="exampleFormControlInput1" enabled>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <td>
            <img src = "{{ book.cover }}" height="150" width="100"/>
        </td>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <br>
        <label for="FormControlSelect1">Select Users</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="FormControlSelect1" required
                    name="user">
            {%  for user in users %}
            <option value="{{ user.pk }}">{{ user }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Reserve</button><br>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ book.pk }}" name="book" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

My reserve html might have some error. it should link my reserve to another page. but it didnt.

[image]

Comment: share your error log

Comment: shared  pls help

Answer (score 0):

Error in the above image `MultiValueDictKeyError`. You have to replace the below code

```
reservation = Reserve.objects.get(pk=request.POST['reservation'])
```

to

```
reservation = Reserve.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('reservation'))
```